# Implementing receiving payment by providing an associated address

Tags: erc-20, ether, gas, meta-transactions

How can I implement receiving payment in tokens by simply providing the user with an address associated with him to which he can send tokens that are credited to the contract balance? I have seen this in many projects, e.g. on Polymarket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Such contracts are called "Forwarder contracts"